# How to search unique array values retain the original and change the rest by "&nbsp"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to search the first unique value and change the succeeding value by space. how can I do it? I just need it in listing report without duplicating display of the values.

```
$array = array("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b");

how to find "a" and change the suceeding a by "&nbsp"
how to find "b" and change the suceeding b by "&nbsp"

OUTPUT: $array = array("a", "&nbsp", "&nbsp", "b", "&nbsp", "&nbsp", "&nbsp");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there has to be a better way, but in the meantime:

```
$array = array("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b");

$result=array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
  if (! in_array($value, $result)) {
    array_push($result,$value);
  } else {
    array_push($result,"&nbsp");
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

This will get you something like an "array_unique" but replacing all repeated values with "&nbsp" no matter the order of the values.

edit: If you need a function that replaces the original array you can use this:

```
$array = array("a", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b","c");

function array_replace_repeat(&$array) {
  $tmpArr=$array;
  $array=array();
  foreach ($tmpArr as $value) {
    if (! in_array($value, $array)) {
      array_push($array,$value);
    } else {
      array_push($array,"&nbsp");
    }
  }
}

array_replace_repeat($array);
```

Comment: Thanks nice code its working in single array output. Actually in my case I just need to change the column/element of my base array but not to create another array() output how can I do that? let say I just want to change only the year column of my existing array. thank you.

Comment: can you give me an example of the array you need to modify?

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => John Doe [datejoin] => 2018-06-16 [username] => John [start_date] => 2017-03-12 [end_date] => 2017-03-12 [leave_type] => Sick Leave [workdays] => 2.0 [year] => 2017 [leave_alloted] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => John Doe [datejoin] => 2018-06-16 [username] => John [start_date] => 2017-03-12 [end_date] => 2017-03-12 [leave_type] => Annual Leave [workdays] => 2.0 [Year] => 2017 [leave_alloted] => 7 )

Comment: I want to print only year and leave_alloted in my table first value then the rest space. thank you. I am using codeigniter

Comment: This is my loop: <?php foreach ($results as $data) {?><?php  
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->year; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->leave_alloted; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->start_date; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->end_date; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->workdays; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php }; ?>

how can I print the year in my array only once the suceeding year become blank or space.

Comment: @rm_beginners you should accept this answer if it solved your first question, and further questions should be posted as new questions and not in comments.